# How to use smooth-scroll css property in safari

Tags: html, css

so I have a back to top button that is supposed to scroll smoothly because I used `scroll-behavior:smooth;` property in css.

```
html {
     scroll-behavior:smooth;
}
```

This works fine in google chrome, but in safari it snaps to the top instead of smooth scroll. How do I fix this?

Comment: try this                                                                                                                                   `html {
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
            -webkit-scroll-behavior: smooth; /* Safari and Chrome */
            -moz-scroll-behavior: smooth; /* Firefox */
            -ms-scroll-behavior: smooth; /* Internet Explorer */
        }`

Comment: Hi @Rainy,
In your solution, Safari does have partial support for the scroll-behavior property, but it may not always provide the desired smooth scrolling effect. 

This property is still considered experimental and its behavior may vary across different browser versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution.

```js
document.getElementById('back-to-top').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const target = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href'));
  target.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
});
```

```css
#back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  /* Additional styling for the back to top button */
}

#back-to-top.show {
  display: block;
  /* Additional styling for the back to top button when it is shown */
}
```

```html
<a href="#top" id="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without changing the javascript? this is my current js: 'function toTop() {
    document.getElementById("top").scrollIntoView();
}'

Comment: Hi @HTMLNerd_1, Unfortunately, in this case, it is not possible to achieve the desired smooth scrolling behavior without modifying the JavaScript.

Comment: As I said before, these CSS properties have limited browser support and may not provide the same consistent smooth scrolling experience across different browsers.